# How should I refer to a person without identifying them? Can I use 'one'?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, singular-they, indefinite-pronouns

If I wish to refer to an individual person but without describing that person or drawing attention to the characteristics of that person or without identifying that person - how should I do it ?

The indefinite personal pronoun 'one' is, commonly, these days, only used in relation to oneself. I believe that, archaically, it was possible to refer to someone else as 'one'. 'One is in the drawing room' did not, necessarily, mean 'I am in the drawing room', only that there was an undetermined occupant in the drawing room.

I understand that the plural personal pronoun 'they' has been used, from Shakesperean times, I believe, to refer to a singular individual. But the plural is somewhat of a contrivance and I suspect that the indefinite personal pronoun is the more correct way.

Is the indefinite pronoun usage (in referring to an unidentified person) too archaic for modern use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Somebody is in the drawing room** or **There is somebody in the drawing room** expresses your meaning better than "one is in the drawing room".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/somebody) explains the meaning of *somebody*: "one or some person of unspecified or indefinite identity".

It is often used in opposition to *nobody* or other negatives, and indicates the presence of at least one person, as in questions like "Is somebody there?" which is asking if there is anybody regardless of their identity.

*One* is not normally used to mean an indefinite person. It has several uses, but the relevant ones are (1) as you say, a substitute for the first person - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one) gives as an example "I'd like to read more but one doesn't have the time." Or (2) to express anybody at all in a general statement such as "one never knows", "one should always check the power is disconnected...", often with "always" or "never", but not usually in a specific statement about a particular place or time.

You can also say "one is in the drawing room" as an elliptical version of "one person is in the drawing room", e.g. in response to the question "Where are the police officers?" "One is in the drawing room." But absent a question or similar context, it would sound odd.

Answer (score 1):

I think either someone or somebody could be used, so either

> Someone is in the drawing room.

or

> Somebody is in the drawing room.

work equally well.

You could then use they to refer to that person to avoid repetition, such as

> Someone is in the drawing room. They are making a lot of noise.